# ServiceStack Razor View wraps content with extra data

Tags: servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack with the Razor plugin and returning response objects from my service methods. If the service uses a default view then the response is fine, but if I specify a View in the service method then the http response includes additional data surrounding the content.

Here's a test service class:

```
[DefaultView("TestView")]
public class TestService : RestServiceBase<Req>
{
    public override object OnGet(Req request)
    {
        var response = new Req { Data = "Hello" };
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Data))
        {
            return response;
        }
        return new HttpResult(response) { View = "TestView" };
    }
}
```

An example raw response including the additional content data looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.3
Date: Thu, 03 Jan 2013 12:46:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.928 Unix/Mono
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Set-Cookie: ss-id=KvFQKAyOkkKMajEFeaLiKQ==; path=/
Set-Cookie: ss-pid=nrv3gwEL6EuRE9B8VpAWZA==; path=/; expires=Mon, 03 Jan 2033 12:43:57 GMT

b1
a4
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Test page</h1>
<p>Hello</p>

</body>
</html>

0


0
```

They look like content length values and end markers. I guess I have something mis-configured, but don't know what. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you update to the latest version of Mono + ServiceStack and see if this still happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated to ServiceStack 3.933. My Mono version is current at 2.10.8.1. The results are the same.

Comment: Update- having tested a little more, the problem appears only on requests to the mono server, not when viewing pages in debug on IIS Express.